# Exercise on localization as a colimit

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am doing the following exercise:

> Suppose $S$ is a multiplicative set of $A$, an integral domain, and interpret $S^{-1}A = \varinjlim \dfrac{1}{s}A$, where the limit is over $s \in S$ and in the category of $A$-modules.

I thought I had an answer but I don't think I have used the fact that $A$ is an integral domain so I am skeptical of my answer now. I would appreciate an answer (with explanation where the integral domain hypothesis is used). Thanks!

Comment: $A$ doesn't need to be an integral domain. The localization is always well-defined; the natural map $A \to S^{-1} A$ is just not necessarily injective in general.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Right. I understand that localization is well defined even if $A$ is not an integral domain. But I was wondering can we interpret $S^{-1}A$ as the above colimit even if $A$ is not an integral domain?

Comment: Yes, it works. If anything what you need is that $A$ is commutative.

Comment: I see. Ok. Thanks!

Comment: Or that $S$ is actually a subset of the center $Z(A)$ (so that the relation is indeed an equivalence relation)!